# Are there any magic characters in Twilio <Say> verbs

Tags: text-to-speech, twilio

Are there any other characters I can use in a [`<Say>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) to help the pronunciation (assuming I have too many options to just record them all as MP3s).

Thus far all I've found is hyphens to help with correctly detecting syllables:
Adgrok is pronounced "Addbrooke" but "Ad-grok" is pronounced correctly.  "PagerDuty" is "pahdgerduty" but "pager-duty" is correct.

Capitals seem to be meaningless and spaces can introduce weirdness: "Mont Re Al." is pronounced "Mont Re Alabama"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time there are no special punctuation marks that can help with pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

I use spaces and periods sometimes but other that that it can be hard when you are using trade names. Another trick is I wanted it to say mysite.com so i typed "mysite dot com" or spelling out numbers five for 5. I think a lot of it comes down to trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

The standard for doing this is SSML (http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/). While Twilio does not support this, Tropo does with their speech synthesis verb 'say'. So, you may do something like this:

```
answer 
say "<speak> I like squirrels!. 
I <prosody rate='-10%'>like squirrels!</prosody> 
I <prosody rate='-30%'>like squirrels!</prosody>  
I <prosody rate='-50%'>like squirrels!</prosody> 
</speak>"  
hangup
```